# How to create validation with 2 uppercase letter and number?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Assuming this is the student id `CC201801194`, I want to restrict from inputting lowercase like this `cc20181194`. They should be only input 2 string 9 numbers.

This is what I have got:

```
$.validator.addMethod("noCaps", function(value, element) {
   return this.optional(element) || /[A-Z]{2}/.test(value); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Can be achieved straight in the HTML markup (without any JS) using the [pattern attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/pattern).

```
<input type="text" pattern="[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{9}">
```

```css
input + span:after {
  position: absolute;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
p.hint {
  display: none;
}
input:valid + span:after {
  content: "✓";
}
input:placeholder-shown + span:after{
  content: "";
}
input:invalid + span:after {
  content: "✖";
}
input:invalid + span + p.hint {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" pattern="[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{9}" Placeholder="Student ID">
  <span class="validity"></span>
  <p class="hint">Student ID must be 2 capitals and 9 numbers.</p>
</form>
```

Comment: thank you for this! I wish i can vote already. I have one more question  ` return this.optional(element) || /^[A-Z]{1}$/.test(value); `  I'm trying to validate in which the first letter should be in upper case and the rest it lower case

Comment: Have a look at [Regex101](https://regex101.com/#javascript).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$.validator.addMethod("noCaps", function(value, element) {
   return this.optional(element) || /[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{9}/.test(value); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
$("#...").keydown(function(e) {
    var test = /[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{9}/; //regex
    //...      
});
```